# How can I label the result of a mathematical equation in a Google Sheets Query and then order it by that label?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am trying to discern the base percentage points change in two columns in a query statement and then order by the results.

I have tried to label the result and Order By that label, but this doesn't work.

```
=QUERY('Sample Sheet'!A:I,"SELECT A,B, ((I-H)/H)*10000 LIMIT 5")
```

I would like the ((I-H)/H)*10000 to be that which I order by. Currently, the Limit statement brings the top 5 results. I don't want to Order By H or I because it is the change in the two numbers I want to display.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY(A:I,"SELECT A,B, ((I-H)/H)*10000 WHERE A IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ((I-H)/H)*10000 LIMIT 5",1)
```

- `ORDER BY` can be used with the same expression used in `SELECT`

Answer (score 0):

you could use double query and have it nice and clean like:

```
=QUERY(QUERY('Sample Sheet'!A:I, 
 "select A,B,((I-H)/H)*10000", 1), 
 "order by Col3 desc
  limit 5
  label Col3'equation'", 1)
```

---

but if you prefer one query then:

```
=QUERY('Sample Sheet'!A:I, 
 "select A,B,((I-H)/H)*10000 
  order by ((I-H)/H)*10000 desc 
  limit 5
  label ((I-H)/H)*10000'equation'", 1)
```